# Two domains, two servers, one dynamic IP address

Tags: windows, apache-http-server

I have two domains hi.org and bye.net and one dynamic IP address and two servers. I want to attach one domain bye.net to server1 and hi.org to server2. I'm using Apache wamp 2.0i.

I have two servers behind one router with a dynamic IP address

```
#httpd.conf file additions

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

</IfModule>


#vhost file additions
NameVirtualHost *:80

#default
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/fallback"
</VirtualHost>


# Server 1
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
ServerName h**p://bye.net
ServerAlias bye.net
</VirtualHost>


# Server 2
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / h**p://192.168.1.119/
DocumentRoot "g:/wamp/www"
ServerName h**p://hi.org
ServerAlias hi.org 
</VirtualHost>
```

After doing all this I fallback to server1 only I don't get the page hi.org I only get the page bye.net, I don't even get the default fallback page  which gets executed when a person enters IP address but not the domain name.

I use Windows 7 (server 2) and Windows XP (server 1)

**UPDATE:**

I needed to remove DocumentRoot "g:/wamp/www" line :D it was there by mistake! things are working fine now.

But one thing: the URL gets replaced by the local ip address any way to not make that happen?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a answer:

A> to run servers you will need a static IP address. HOWEVER you can use something like dyns.net who follow your IP and give it a web address.

Answer A only functions to allow your www. to go to the correct public IP address.

B> Two servers... why?
Using virtual name based hosting, you can run two different Domain names from one server.
What you do is simply this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

#default
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/fallback"
</VirtualHost>


# Server 1
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
ServerName bye.net
ServerAlias bye.net
</VirtualHost>


# Server 2
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/hi orgs folder"
ServerName hi.org
ServerAlias hi.org 
</VirtualHost>
```

Effectively what you are doing is:

Apache looks up the URL referal header.
Apache then:
Forwards requests for bye.net to wampp/www

and for hi.org
apache forwards requests to /hi orgs folder (or root)

You can put the root anywhere, and users just type the address and do to the actual website.

**More on this here:** http://www.gtwcmt.co.uk/virtual-host-creation-in-apache-windows/

your H**P is not needed, though you can add http:// www. hi.org to direct trafic (http port 80)  if there is no responce from the websites.

You dont need to run two servers.

C>
Two run two servers (physical) you would change your *:80 to public IP:80
Your router then needs to set bridge (DMZ) using Public IP's on the computer system holding the servers.
This is known as pass-through, bridging. You should seach on the net for your router to see how to do this.

You will also need to rent (purchase) two Public IP addresses, speak to your ISP for  info and costs.

Comment: *You dont need to run two servers* -- but that IS the premise of this very question.